# Check Enumerator values if present using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, dataset, linq-to-objects

```
public enum Test
{
  A = 0,
  B = 1,
  C = 2,
  D = 3,
  E = 4,
  F = 5,
  G = 6
}

DataSet oDsEnum = new DataSet();
DataTable oDtEnum = new DataTable();

oDtEnum.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ENUM_ID", typeof(int)));
oDtEnum.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ENUM_VALUE", typeof(int)));

oDtEnum.Rows.Add(10, 1001);
oDtEnum.Rows.Add(21, 1002);
oDtEnum.Rows.Add(2, 1003);
oDtEnum.Rows.Add(300, 1004);
oDtEnum.Rows.Add(4, 1005);

oDsEnum.Tables.Add(oDtEnum);
oDsEnum.AcceptChanges();
```

I want to check if the Column "ENUM_ID" of DataSet "oDsEnum" contains the value of the Enumerator "Test" for further operation using LINQ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var enumValues = (
    from int val in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Test))
    select val
).ToArray();
```

If you just want to know if there are any such values, use `Any`:

```
var query = oDtEnum.AsEnumerable().Any(
    row => enumValues.Contains(row.Field<int>("ENUM_ID"))
);
```

If you need the values themselves:

```
var query = 
    from row in oDtEnum.AsEnumerable()
    where enumValues.Contains(row.Field<int>("ENUM_ID"))
    select row;
```

Comment: +1 for performance, but you can use `var enumValues = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Test)).Cast<int>().ToArray()`

Comment: Which is what `int val` does in the `enumValues` query.

Comment: I know that. But one operator `Cast<int>` is much shorter than `from int val in ... select val`

Comment: Point taken; unless you prefer keyword syntax.

Comment: @lazyberezovsky There must be a way to do this in a single query. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

This will check if column has values from enum:

```
oDsEnum.AsEnumerable()
       .Any(row => Enum.IsDefined(typeof(Test), row.Field<int>("ENUM_ID")));
```

If you want to select rows, which have value from enum in `ENUM_ID` field, use `Where` instead of `Any`.

*UPDATE* single-query (I think best performance also):

```
var query = from row in oDtEnum.AsEnumerable()
            join t in Enum.GetValues(typeof (Test)).Cast<Test>()
                on row.Field<Test>("ENUM_ID") equals t
            select row;
```

Comment: +1 for elegance, but there appear to be some performance issues with `Enum.IsDefined` - see [here](http://goldfishforthought.blogspot.co.il/2008/03/isbadenumisdefined-true.html) and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2003/11/29/50903.aspx).